# How to solve Kinematics: two objects meeting in the air

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, projectile

A water balloon is dropped from the top of a 200m high tower. An alert archer at the base of the tower sees the balloon being dropped, waits for 5s, then shoots an arrow at 40m/s straight up towards the balloon. How far has the balloon fallen when it is struck by the arrow? 
The answer is 168.9m but I don't know how to get that.

Comment: The balloon will fall down under gravitational force. First, find how long the balloon moves under that gravitational force in 5 seconds. If you find this, it means you also know the distance between the balloon and the archer right at that moment. Then, you can think of the problem as if you have two cars moving towards each other with some accelerations and you are asked to find the distance taken by one of the cars until the time they collide. Necessary equations to solve the problem are easy and can be found in many books.

Comment: mate can we do this with x and y displacement/velocity components separately considered.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the position (as a function of time) for the balloon with simple kinematics:

$y_B=200-\dfrac{1}{2}gt_B^2$

(with $g=+9.8\:m/s^2$).

After five seconds, the archer shoots the arrow upward, the position of which can also be represented with kinematics:

$y_A=40t-\dfrac{1}{2}gt_A^2$

Now, they're on separate time scales, where $t_i=0$ corresponds to the time of drop/launch. So then all you need is a relation between the times. When the archer launches, we say $t_A=0$. At this time, the balloon has seen five seconds elapse, so that $t_B=5\:sec$. From that point onwards, time elapses at the same rate for the two, so:

$t_A=t_B-5$

What remains, then, is to recognize that we want $y_A$ to be equal to $y_B$. You now have three equations with three unknowns. Happy solving.